# Rails: gem/plugin for finding missing indexes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Is there a gem or plugin like https://github.com/eladmeidar/rails_indexes that works for rails3?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can paste following code in your console to know the missing foreign key indexes. This, however, is not as capable of the plugin that you refer to. It only searches for rails style foreign keys that have an `_id` at the end of their column name.

```
c = ActiveRecord::Base.connection
c.tables.collect do |t|  
  columns = c.columns(t).collect(&:name).select {|x| x.ends_with?("_id") || x.ends_with?("_type")}
  indexed_columns = c.indexes(t).collect(&:columns).flatten.uniq
  unindexed = columns - indexed_columns
  unless unindexed.empty?
    puts "#{t}: #{unindexed.join(", ")}"
  end
end
```

[Source](http://tomafro.net/2009/09/quickly-list-missing-foreign-key-indexes)

Comment: There is an error in select block, it should be:                                              `.select { |x| x.ends_with?("_id") || x.ends_with?("_type") }`.

Comment: Very useful if you don't have models and therefore can't use lol_dba. (The repo I'm looking at only manages migrations, because the database itself is used by a React app, not a Rails one)

Comment: As you said, this will not return indexes that are multi-field, custom, and that are written to the schema file. It's better to parse the schema.

Answer (score 24):

There's a fork of rails_indexes that has been updated to work with Rails 3 and Ruby 1.9

https://github.com/plentz/lol_dba